# Why are my Rails cookies lost upon browser close?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session-cookies

I understand that Rails requires some configuration to get the cookies to persist upon browser close. The cookie sets properly and I am able to get the desired result while the browser remains open. However, as soon as I close the browser and re-open it and access the site, the cookie data seems lost.

I did this in the appropriate controller:

```
cookies[:locale] = { value: params[:locale], expires: 1.year.from_now }
```

I also did this in session_store.rb:

```
myApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :expire_after =>  nil,
}
```

A simple command seems likely. What am I missing?

---

EDIT full conditional for clarity -

```
def lang_set
 if params[:locale] != nil
  cookies.permanent[:locale] = params[:locale]
 end
 I18n.locale = cookies[:locale]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def lang_set
 if params[:locale] != nil
  cookies.permanent[:locale] = params[:locale]
 end
 I18n.locale = cookies[:locale]
end
```

Comment: I currently did that. Still seems to not be persisting upon browser close. :(

Comment: You still have to assign a value to the cookie. Try cookies.permanent[:locale] = 12345 and see if it holds. I just tried in my browser and it persists even after I quit and re-open.

Comment: Yes I see, but try giving it a random value like 123 and see if it stays. It works for me. I think the problem may be that params[:locale] is empty. If you give your cookie a constant value, such as an integer, and the cookie persists, then the problem isn't the cookie, rather it is what you're storing in the cookie.

Comment: oh, i see what you're saying. however - that is part of a conditional statement. i'll post on question

Comment: This should do the trick. Thanks for posting the conditional.

Comment: oh so i should be declaring `.permanent` on both get and set? well sheesh. ok will let you know how that goes.

Comment: ok, when i do that i get a `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` error...was this working for you?

Comment: Sorry, that was completely wrong. Remove the line: if params[:locale] != nil to see if it holds the value of params[:locale]

Comment: No worries. The cookie persists while the browser remains open. If I close the tab or move from page to page, it remains in the translation that the cookie stores. It just seems to be that as soon as I close the browser, the cookie data is lost. I did try your suggestion of just removing the params. Nothing changed

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your time. Looks like there are some underlying issues I need to resolve with the app/server. Thanks again.